# Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error - spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

Installed intellij community edition 2022.3.1. Trying to compile a simple scala spark program and getting "Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error" error.

Below is my build.sbt

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

//ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.5"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "untitled"
  )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.4")
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dependency `_2.11` then your Scala version should be 2.11.x.

If your Scala version is 2.13.x (or 2.10.x) then you should use a dependency `_2.13` (or `_2.10` correspondingly).

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core

`"org.apache.spark" %% ...` instead of `"org.apache.spark" % ...` automatically adds proper suffix `_2.13`, `_2.12`, `_2.11`, `_2.10` ...

Current Spark is 3.3.1 (it exists for Scala 2.13.x or 2.12.x), current Scala is 2.13.10 (former are 2.12.17, 2.11.12, 2.10.7).

Former Spark 2.3.4 exists only for Scala 2.11.x, not 2.13.x or 2.10.x.

Version of IntelliJ is now irrelevant.

Try

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.1")
// libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.13" % "3.3.1")
```